# Can I reference a DataContract and its proxy version from same class

Tags: wcf, c#-4.0

I'm dipping my foot into WCF and am trying to make a simple test project that can both consume the service as a service and also directly instantiate it's classes and work with them.

I had an earlier working version where data passed was just primitive types.  However, when I attempted to convert to using data contracts, I'm getting conflicts in whether it's referencing the proxy-declared version of the contract or the version from the project itself.

**Question:**  Is it possible to do this and if so, how would I resolve the data contract references?

```
    private void Test()
    {

        MyService fssDirect = new MyService();    // direct instantiation
        MyServiceClient fssService = new MyServiceClient();    // Service proxy

        ClientCredentialsContract Client = new ClientCredentialsContract();
        ResponseDataContract Result = new ResponseDataContract();

        if (CallAsService)
        {
            Result = fssService.Create(Client, Request);
        }
        else
        {
            Result = fssDirect.Create(Client, Request);
        }
    }
```

In the above, any reference to the RequestDataContract and ClientCredentialsContract types indicates

> Warning:  The type 'MyContracts.RequestDataContract' in 'C:...\Test\MyServiceProxy.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'MyContracts.RequestDataContract' in 'C:...\MyService\bin\Debug\Contracts.dll'.  Using the type defined in 'C:...\Test\MyServiceProxy.cs'.

(Names changed and paths shortened to protect the innocent)

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the proxy for your service, try referencing the assembly which contains the data contracts (if using "Add Service Reference", go to the advanced options, select "reuse types in referenced assemblies"; if using svcutil, use the `/r` argument). This way the tool won't generate the data contracts and you won't have the conflicts.